# WIll the multimeter continuity test on the SOIC - DIP adapter spoil my IC?

Tags: measurement

IC : L9637D for ISO 9141 bi directional serial comm. Multimeter: Mastech

I am mounting an SOIC 8 IC on an adapter(regular Soic to dip adapter), so I can mount the adapter on a bread board for use.

I want to ensure that the pins of my SOIC pins are clamped correctly and firmly, so i use the continuity test between the DIP pin (say DIP pin 1 of the adapter) and the SOIC pin (pin 1 in this case), to see if there is contact in Pin 8, and repeat this for 8 pins.

Will this type of testing damage the IC? Obviously i thought that current wont be flowing directly through the IC in this case. These ICs are incredibly tough to get and common sense tells me it wont but just to be sure.

PS : i am not testing between pins of the same SOIC, just between the adapter and the SOIC. Thanks for any of the help :)

Comment: The current *might* flow through the IC in case there is no contact of the tested pin with the socket. In such a case it might find a path through your circuit and the other pins connected to it.

Comment: your question cannot be answered ... you have not provided any information about the device that you are using to measure continuity ..... note: you should measure the resistance instead of continuity

Comment: @jsotola sorry about that.. info added. Will resistance measurement be safer? say the lowest (200 ohm) setting?

Comment: Consider optical inspection instead; a 10x loupe should be sufficient, though a stereo zoom microscope if a very nice tool and not all that expensive today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuity measurement won't hurt the IC.  ESD still can, so take appropriate precautions.  Since you didn't specify the IC, I can't guess whether checking for shorts between pins poses any danger; in most cases it won't.

Comment: Sorry about that I added the name of the IC to the post. In this case I am not measuring between 2 pins of the IC, Im only testing it between the dip pin of adapter and the corresponding Soic pin.